# Why does useState update in DOM but not in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a little puzzled here and would appreciate if somebody could explain why `useState` exhibits this behaviour. I have a functional component using `useState` which starts a timer and renders the time correctly in real time in the the DOM. Upon stopping the timer I'd like to push the time to an array, but every attempt to do so simply pushed 0 - the initial state of the `time` variable.

After some debugging I noticed that if I `console.log()` the time inside of the interval-looped function it also continues to log 0, and not the "real" time.

Here's my code. I've cut out all of the parts irrelevent to the problem at hand.

```
export default function Timer() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const interval = useRef(null);

    clearInterval(interval.current);
    let startTime = Date.now() - time;
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(Date.now() - startTime);            
        console.log(time); // <-- Why does this continue to show 0?
    }, 10);

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 60000) % 1000)).slice(-2)}:</span>
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 1000) % 1000)).slice(-2)}.</span>
            <span>{("00" + (time % 1000)).slice(-3, -1)}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So my question is, why does the `time` variable return the correct time **in real time** inside of the DOM but not in the console? I thought it may be due to useState not being instant so to speak, but I don't get why it would just continue logging 0.

**EDIT:**

I fixed this issue by declaring a separate variable `curTime = 0` and instead of using `setTime(Date.now() - startTime)`, I used `curTime = (Date.now() - startTime)`:

```
export default function Timer() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const interval = useRef(null);
    let curTime = 0

    clearInterval(interval.current);
    let startTime = Date.now() - time;
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        curTime = (Date.now() - startTime);     
        setTime(curTime)    
        console.log(curTime); // <-- Now shows correct time.
    }, 10);

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 60000) % 1000)).slice(-2)}:</span>
            <span>{("0" + Math.floor((time / 1000) % 1000)).slice(-2)}.</span>
            <span>{("00" + (time % 1000)).slice(-3, -1)}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `time` in the interval function is always going to be the same variable that was originally set because the interval function is a closure. If you want the most up-to-date one then you need to acess it in a `useEffect`

Comment: Would this still work if the entire section of code I've includes is wrapped inside of its own function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React uses a declarative style.  The value of the state will change when the component rerenders.  You are logging before that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I had read that, but if the DOM is rerendering every 10ms, why does the console still show the initial value? I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding how useState works.

Comment: The console is showing that value because it hasn't rerendered and you should treat it as continuing to execute code.  You can think of rerendering as all the code being executed from the beginning of your functional component again.  It does not interrupt the current execution and substitute new values.   After the rerender, the only values it will 'remember' between re-renders are what are stored in state (or possibly in global variables which you should avoid).  The new values will be shown then and only then in the variable you get back from `useState`

Answer (score 1):

```
let startTime = Date.now() - time;
interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setTime(Date.now() - startTime);            
    console.log(time); // <-- Why does this continue to show 0?
}, 10);
```

From what I understand, you are trying to print the updated state value in the following line of setting the state. This will not work in the general case. The reason being the setter of the state is asynchronous in nature. It means, anytime you run setTime/setState, it will be called by React at that place itself but its updated value will only be visible on the next render. That is why your DOM shows an updated value (after every rerender). Always remember, your function execution is synchronous so the following line will be executed at that time itself but the updated state will be visible on the next render.
Having said that React team realized there might be cases when state update has to behave synchronously.

For that, they designed 'flushSync'. You can check more here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync (This is not recommended by React team and should only be used when async updates of state don't help.)

Comment: I've fixed my code by declaring another variable as the timer's time, and then calling setTime as that new variable's value. That way I have the time displayed in the DOM and a time to push to an array.

Comment: No, what you have done in 2nd code snippet is not showing the updated time state but it is showing 'curTime' value you assigned at 'curTime = (Date.now() - startTime);'. Also, when you print console.log(time), it will try to show previous most update state value not currently updated. My guess is your timer is not clearing properly and since it is setInterval, multiple intervals are running and because of closure, intervals are showing old values. If you try to achieve using setTimeout, you will see the last updated time value every time on console.log(time).